# Getting exception in JDBC thin driver

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I try to run the query using the Java and below mentioned is my program

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.naming.spi.DirStateFactory.Result;
public class Oracleconn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:yglobal","user","user");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select empid from empmaster");
            while(rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getint(1));
            con.close();            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
}
```

But when i tried to run this program I am getting the exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:790)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1038)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:830)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1273)
at jdbc.Oracleconn.main(Oracleconn.java:28)
```

Comment: I think this `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated` is the Problem. `;`

Comment: I don't think your sample code would ever produce that error message.

Comment: Use rs.getInt(1) instead of res.getint(1) in while.

Comment: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
Cause: A quoted string must be terminated with a single quote mark (').
Action: Insert the closing quote and retry the statement.

Comment: @aashish_soni: `rs.getint(1)` wouldn't even compile, so that is probably not the problem

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name I wouldn't expect the code shown to give this error (and with the typo mentioned by aashish_soni this wouldn't even compile). So I have to assume this isn't your real code: please show the actual query!

Comment: agree with you guys but i was just trying to correct the code not fixing code ....